# Which executes first? Form_Load event or the initialization of components? (C# windows form)

Tags: c#, winforms

Which executes first? Form_Load event or the initialization of components? (C# windows form)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Components will be initialized before form load.

See [this](http://www.csharp411.com/c-winforms-form-event-order/) article about form event order.

Answer (score 6):

All the components of a Form are inialized first, then the Form is loaded

Answer (score 5):

The initialization of component is happened in constructor (Designer automatically insert initializecomponent in constructor) while the `form_load` event fired when the form is displayed first time.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean InitializeComponent() method, then it executes first from constructor. If you subscribe for  Form_Load  event from designer subscription code will be added to InitializeComponent.